# Why does my browser share the installed fonts?

Tags: firefox, fonts, chromium, privacy, fingerprinting

The browser doesn't share the fonts in the http request. Nevertheless, the fonts can be analyzed via javascript.

Is it possible to prevent javascript to analyze my installed fonts?

---

### Old Question:

When visiting a website the request send from my browser to the server contains the fonts installed on my system.

Why does this happen? Why does the browser share the installed fonts for 3rd party requests like images or scripts?

Afaik many websites will just download any font from the internet to present the website correctly. So there is no necessity for the server to know the locally installed fonts. Furthermore, I doubt any design personalization based on the available fonts (am I wrong?).

Is there any possibility to block the broadcasting of this data, to prevent fingerprinting for example?

Comment: Browsers do not do that by default. Your problem seems better suited to Super User.

Comment: Browsers do this by default. See [browserleaks](https://browserleaks.com/fonts) or [panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/)

Comment: There is a **massive** difference between "A website uses JavaScript to fingerprint the fonts installed in a browser and then continues to use JavaScript to post a list of those fonts to the server" and "The browser sends a list of fonts to the server by default". Are you asking how to stop that fingerprinting? It still sounds like a problem for SuperUser.

Comment: Ahh I see. I got sth wrong. But how can I disable to share my installed fonts via javascript. (except for blocking the whole script?)